# Add Visual Studio solution to existing solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, import

I wrote an application in Visual Studio C# 2010, that I would like to import into another existing Visual Studio C# 2010 Application. How would I go about doing this?

For instance, I'd like to import the project into another, and basically copy/paste the interface from the application into a tabpage on a tab control I have.

Any assistance or advice on how to do this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If what you are wanting is a "copy and paste" of just some of the code files, adding them as links would probably be best.

Comment: You can't just right click on your solution and click Add > Existing Project?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy the physical files using windows from the existing solution location to the new solution location.

Then once the copy is complete open Visual studio and tell it you want to add an existing project. Navigate to the folder where the files are on the filesystem and open the project file.

Once you save the solution it should from that point forward have the new projects in the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this - Copy & Paste being one of them (but the least beautiful of course). A more promising one is the following:

- Wrap the user interface you want to share in a User Control in the existing project. Also include the code behind logic in this user control. Include the user control in the project and make sure that everything works before continuing.
- Add the existing project to the new solution. It is advised that you create a hierarchical structure in the file system for the solution so that all projects in the solution are located under a directory.
- Reference the project from the project that wants to access the user interface. As the projects are in the same solution, you can add a project reference. This asserts that the projects are built together.
- Place the user control on the tab page.

As an alternative, you can also pass on adding the project to the solution but only create a user control and add a binary reference from the other project.